# From address in send Email in SharePoint Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, designer-workflow

I have a requirement that I need to use a different from address in email workflow in a particular sub site.
I know that if we change it in Central admin it effect all the site collections in SharePoint but I don't want to do that as it effects for all sites and all workflows.

I want to do it only for one subsite workflow

Comment: please refer this link -- http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/142193/how-to-change-workflow-email-sender-name

Comment: I am asking about to change complete name and email of from adress. for example 
1. We have HR subsite when an employee joined office the HR will send an email automatically using "HR@gmail.com"  the workflow written for employee list when employee record added the email triggered through workflow
2. We have Finance department sub site For tax declaration Finance has to send email to the employee for tax declarations
here we need to set from Address is "finance@gmail.com"

both sub sites are under one site collection and using Designer workflows. how do we change the from addresses ?

Comment: SharePoint only uses one, centrally configured outgoing e-mail address per web application

Comment: How do we achieve this ? any alternate solution ?